# Performance issue with Rust vs Python

Tags: python, rust, cryptography

After reading an [article about "Memorable Unique Identifiers"](https://www.gkbrk.com/2022/10/memorable-unique-identifiers-muid/) and seeing the author mention that they want to try to rewrite the example Python code to C to achieve better performance, I tried rewriting it to Rust and I was very surprised by the Rust version being considerably **slower** than the Python version.

Tested on a 2021 M1 Pro MacBook Pro with `Python 3.10.9` and `nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin, rustc 1.69.0-nightly (07c993eba 2023-02-23)`.

Python version from the article (sligtly edited from original)

```py
import json
import hashlib
import os

TARGET_DIFF = 8

prefixes = set()

with open("animals.json") as f:
    f = json.load(f)
    for key in f.keys():
        if len(key) == TARGET_DIFF:
            prefixes.add(key)

counter = 0

while counter < 10:
    buf = os.urandom(16).hex()
    h = hashlib.sha256(buf.encode("utf-8")).digest().hex()
    if h[:TARGET_DIFF] in prefixes:
        print(buf, h)
        counter += 1
```

This manages to find 10 hashes in about 7 seconds.

```
> time python3 miner.py
python3 miner.py  7.60s user 3.00s system 99% cpu 10.626 total
```

My attempt to rewrite this to Rust:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    path::Path,
    fmt::Error,
    env,
    process
};

use core::fmt::Write;

use sha256;

use rand_xoshiro::rand_core::SeedableRng;
use rand_xoshiro::Xoshiro256PlusPlus;
use rand::Rng;

const TARGET_DIFF: usize = 8;

fn lines_from_file(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Vec<String> {
    let file = File::open(filename).expect("no such file");
    let buf = BufReader::new(file);
    
    buf.lines()
        .map(|l| l.expect("could not parse line"))
        .filter(|s| s.len() == TARGET_DIFF)
        .collect()
}

fn to_hex(input: &mut [u8]) -> Result<String, Error> {
    let mut s = String::with_capacity(2 * input.len());
    
    for byte in input {
        write!(s, "{:02x}", byte)?;
    }
    
    Ok(s)
}

fn fill_with_random(input: &mut [u8], rng: &mut Xoshiro256PlusPlus) -> Result<(), Error> {
    for i in 0..input.len() {
        input[i] = rng.gen::<u8>();
    }
    
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    
    if args.len() < 2 {
        println!("Usage: ./muid <seed>");
        process::exit(1);
    }
    
    let seed: i32 = match args[1].parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(error) => {
            println!("Invalid argument: {:?}", error);
            process::exit(1);
        },
    };
    
    let mut rng = Xoshiro256PlusPlus::seed_from_u64(seed.try_into().unwrap());
    let lines = lines_from_file("keywords");
   
    println!("{0} {1: >31} {2: >61}", "Private Key", "Public Key", "Keyword");
    println!("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    
    let mut counter = 0;
    
    while counter < 10 {
        let mut rand: [u8; 16] = [0; 16];
        fill_with_random(&mut rand, &mut rng).unwrap();
        
        let rand_str = to_hex(&mut rand).unwrap();
        let data_digest = sha256::digest(rand_str.clone());

        let head = &data_digest[..TARGET_DIFF];
        
        if lines.contains(&head.to_string()) {
            println!("{} {} {}", rand_str, data_digest, head);
            counter += 1;
        } 
    }
}
```

Compiled with `cargo build --release`, it finds 10 hashes in over 44 seconds...

```
> ./target/release/uid 0
./target/release/muid 0  44.79s user 0.13s system 99% cpu 44.986 total
```

My guess would be either user error because I'm new to Rust or the RNG being slower in Rust for some reason. Can someone please explain why the Rust version is so much slower?

Comment: You could try just timing the RNG on its own to eliminate that possibility.  I don't know the details of the two RNGs but it's not hard to imagine that one might be slower and/or less predictable than the other.

Comment: provide json example, your two code are different even on the parsing, to compare two thing you must minimize the number of different, here you compare json parsing, manual verification, random generation, argument parsing...

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are using a vastly slower code than the python version.

- `fill_with_random` is horribly slow. It fills the array byte by byte. Use `rng.fill_bytes()` directly.
- Why did you use `rand_xoshiro`? I am uncertain what its performance characteristics are for generating the random data you need. Either way, it's most certainly not optimized for generating `u8` numbers. I'd personally try the default `thread_rng()` first.
- Don't convert back and forth between strings and bytes. Every conversion is a memory allocation. Also, don't use `.clone()` if not necessary, this again causes a memory allocation. Preferredly don't convert at all; digests are raw bytes, so keep everything as raw bytes.
- To achieve that, don't use an SHA256 implementation that returns a hex string. It can't be efficient, as it already did an allocation and conversion internally. `sha2::Sha256` is most widely used and provides a byte array digest, as intended.
- Use [`clap`](https://docs.rs/clap) for your command line. This has nothing to do with the question you asked, it's just nicer and easier than writing your own parser :)
- Use a proper json parser to read your json input file. The inofficial standard for this in Rust is `serde_json`.
- Don't use a `Vec` for a `contains()` operation - it's horribly slow, as it is in `O(n)`. Use `HashSet` instead, it can perform the same task in `O(log n)`. The `contains()` operation is kind of the entire justification for why `HashSet` exists in the first place.

With all that fixed, here's a working version:

```rust
use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, HashSet},
    fs::File,
    io::BufReader,
    path::Path,
};

use hex::FromHex;
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};

use rand::{thread_rng, RngCore};

const TARGET_DIFF: usize = 8;
const TARGET_DIFF_BYTES: usize = TARGET_DIFF / 2;

fn lines_from_file(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> HashSet<[u8; TARGET_DIFF_BYTES]> {
    let file = File::open(filename).expect("no such file");
    let buf = BufReader::new(file);

    let data: HashMap<String, [u8; 2]> =
        serde_json::from_reader(buf).expect("Unable to parse input data!");

    data.keys()
        .filter_map(|s| <[u8; TARGET_DIFF_BYTES]>::from_hex(s).ok())
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let lines = lines_from_file("animals.json");

    let mut rng = thread_rng();

    println!(
        "{0} {1: >31} {2: >61}",
        "Private Key", "Public Key", "Keyword"
    );
    println!("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    let mut counter = 0;

    while counter < 10 {
        let mut rand: [u8; 16] = [0; 16];
        rng.fill_bytes(&mut rand);

        let data_digest = Sha256::digest(&rand);
        let head = &data_digest[..TARGET_DIFF_BYTES];

        if lines.contains(head) {
            println!(
                "{} {} {}",
                hex::encode(rand),
                hex::encode(data_digest),
                hex::encode(head)
            );
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

On my PC, I get ~15 seconds for the Python code, and ~4 seconds for the Rust code.

---

I did try `Xoshiro256PlusPlus`, but it didn't seem to make much of a difference. If anything, it felt a little slower.

---

Now comes the actual part why you use Rust, though. You can do further optimization that is impossible in Python. In this case, the code would benefit drastically from multithreading - a concept that simply doesn't exist in Python due to the [global interpreter lock (GIL)](https://realpython.com/python-gil/).

Here is a simple multithreaded version of your code:

```rust
use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, HashSet},
    fs::File,
    io::BufReader,
    path::Path,
    sync::atomic::{AtomicU8, Ordering},
    time::Instant,
};

use hex::FromHex;
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};

use rand::{thread_rng, RngCore};

const TARGET_DIFF: usize = 8;
const TARGET_DIFF_BYTES: usize = TARGET_DIFF / 2;

fn lines_from_file(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> HashSet<[u8; TARGET_DIFF_BYTES]> {
    let file = File::open(filename).expect("no such file");
    let buf = BufReader::new(file);

    let data: HashMap<String, [u8; 2]> =
        serde_json::from_reader(buf).expect("Unable to parse input data!");

    data.keys()
        .filter_map(|s| <[u8; TARGET_DIFF_BYTES]>::from_hex(s).ok())
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    let lines = lines_from_file("animals.json");

    let t1 = Instant::now();

    println!(
        "{0} {1: >31} {2: >61}",
        "Private Key", "Public Key", "Keyword"
    );
    println!("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    let counter: AtomicU8 = AtomicU8::new(0);

    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        for thread_id in 0..num_cpus::get() {
            let lines = &lines;
            let counter = &counter;
            scope.spawn(move || {
                let mut rng = thread_rng();

                while counter.load(Ordering::Relaxed) < 10 {
                    let mut rand: [u8; 16] = [0; 16];
                    rng.fill_bytes(&mut rand);

                    let data_digest = Sha256::digest(rand);
                    let head = &data_digest[..TARGET_DIFF_BYTES];

                    if lines.contains(head) {
                        println!(
                            "{} {} {}  (thread {})",
                            hex::encode(rand),
                            hex::encode(data_digest),
                            hex::encode(head),
                            thread_id
                        );
                        counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    let t2 = Instant::now();

    println!();
    println!("Json parser: {} ms", (t1 - t0).as_millis());
    println!("Computation: {} ms", (t2 - t1).as_millis());
}
```

```
$ time ./target/release/rust_playground 
Private Key                      Public Key                                                       Keyword
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4899c6115970e257f5487a5d7a57df8b a1beba55ba89c9523d6e33ae0896efb95873a04c3a39c143a89e26f69ca00fc0 a1beba55  (thread 1)
ac1e8cc6bf8bb4d03a2feb7afed9d48c 53e76f08669014031bcf2e85ff263f220f883caafd039c107601ae7b4828b3b8 53e76f08  (thread 2)
aa5d4813fe281df2ad982bd630f98f10 3e1ea91e84d3ff3af0c59c262711d084de9a5c1260053aae2ba2b361aa8fd541 3e1ea91e  (thread 6)
bf41fd645743740f32d02fbc9ddaf98e 1e9b00b4117ecd90d6e36e2dc9a36b12620fe20449cc19b7b8f4de6d781557de 1e9b00b4  (thread 5)
7a56d3284dcbdfb070744fef2186071d 3a55aee106225fe476c99b83bebaed50c87702ef00ad9a8fc56fa9d114ef661e 3a55aee1  (thread 7)
f0074e27fd48b60d739b667b708a1d62 be1a70addbf096285d1734891ac6d3b56f06a057683d77b586816ef10599492b be1a70ad  (thread 3)
3b9b98957272e1c079fdd0265d96b834 fe3e90a72fc8f2008624a80dc840a2964405a466d2d6301cb650777c00de46a0 fe3e90a7  (thread 0)
d0db8ceb534fe07d9206c82a920464b2 a71e301e411faa78f87f264efb20a5b01b75125fafddd0728fd19340501faaab a71e301e  (thread 5)
92f2a0d5af8ce2b963cb2e72760de46a 10b3005ebb708ba114850dd99fdc8286101235664121d90e082963314bd23289 10b3005e  (thread 5)
e7c227036024053ae04a55a819b30e4a 7ee57b0af545bfc545277b6f7854ac740b6110b5d1a6eeb1dae002d8c6c10c6b 7ee57b0a  (thread 7)

Json parser: 26 ms
Computation: 926 ms

real    0m0.960s
user    0m7.338s
sys     0m0.062s
```

Compared to 15 seconds in Python. Note that the `real` and `user` differ drastically, which usually doesn't happen in Python. This means the real time was drastically lower than the effective time if you sum up all the time of the individual cores. This is a good thing - it means that our multithreading code works.

To compare, this is my result for the python code:

```
$ time python3 main.py
0b9a4dc5090db954b02bfbb87d571a35 3e564d09959cff5b074726e7535a82a6030ba0295922f71bb1891e01b4516c75
1279f0153e4e847d5908142a1cacf58e a7305b0a806c9f62bb5112efebee9f1d6b8283eb37847a0f134b83aa94aeda00
3e94485a9d09cef92b98e4f4ef9da60d 57e3af14e914bb23c248e8a75ca24abf2b09557fae744a8505ac7a61f4cc3107
9cd343269aa18dcb088b5ceb37d7a42c 30554d09cf8879eb1bf90b1de1040449ada311976c782008718c9d40e885506b
8ab684a1be71c469eba7df5ff2aae11c 5c007f0811ffc2aa5ac00beb9f5ae855151775fa5618483b62814d9344e53924
60880dc454f7c7c06266bbcbde8b6e82 d03e301e1c4eed6ac15768c96221bbec49a0c2efa39f2a161dd0ad89955af35b
d239f0435e2b3f5b8d9416c2f20db09f b01dba55a8241eb97f226158958b39a87f847f0e94ae8b2bf9e7a1fe91fc7ce9
039215379ead9258dd9529dc7ac9f4fd 5a6690a7d25accced56a61919119ceb02a2366418de3cec71cbca41025ed9699
4e6aff88a6145e9a8dd2ab05e2ca1d81 9ab1ef14e7f2d5a0d1758c6a6e905f1874c760408ddd6d091933941367d2a071
a0c2275229200da2357d458447d87d3c 605e1ca7e580712e315961f37c4ff7779873d5212dcd1680340d6430bd93c6b3

real    0m21.578s
user    0m17.667s
sys     0m3.893s
```

---

Here some more minor optimization, although I'm unsure how much (if any) impact they really have:

- Reuse the `SHA256` object instead and don't allocate a buffer for the output every time
- Generate 64 bytes of random data every time (probably doesn't have any effect, simply wanted to try if generating more data at a time would increase performance - I don't think it did)

For production or as a submission I would use the code above. I just wanted to include this as a reference of what else could potentially be changed.

```rust
use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, HashSet},
    fs::File,
    io::BufReader,
    path::Path,
    sync::atomic::{AtomicU8, Ordering},
    time::Instant,
};

use hex::FromHex;
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};

use rand::{thread_rng, RngCore};

const TARGET_DIFF: usize = 8;
const TARGET_DIFF_BYTES: usize = TARGET_DIFF / 2;

fn lines_from_file(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> HashSet<[u8; TARGET_DIFF_BYTES]> {
    let file = File::open(filename).expect("no such file");
    let buf = BufReader::new(file);

    let data: HashMap<String, [u8; 2]> =
        serde_json::from_reader(buf).expect("Unable to parse input data!");

    data.keys()
        .filter_map(|s| <[u8; TARGET_DIFF_BYTES]>::from_hex(s).ok())
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    let lines = lines_from_file("animals.json");

    let t1 = Instant::now();

    println!(
        "{0} {1: >31} {2: >61}",
        "Private Key", "Public Key", "Keyword"
    );
    println!("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    let counter: AtomicU8 = AtomicU8::new(0);

    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        for thread_id in 0..num_cpus::get() {
            let lines = &lines;
            let counter = &counter;
            scope.spawn(move || {
                let mut rng = thread_rng();
                let mut rand: [u8; 64] = [0; 64];

                let mut sha256 = Sha256::new();
                let mut data_digest = [0u8; 32].into();

                while counter.load(Ordering::Relaxed) < 10 {
                    rng.fill_bytes(&mut rand);

                    for i in 0..4 {
                        let data = &rand[i * 16..(i + 1) * 16];
                        sha256.update(data);
                        sha256.finalize_into_reset(&mut data_digest);

                        let head = &data_digest[..TARGET_DIFF_BYTES];

                        if lines.contains(head) {
                            println!(
                                "{} {} {}  (thread {})",
                                hex::encode(data),
                                hex::encode(data_digest),
                                hex::encode(head),
                                thread_id
                            );
                            counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    let t2 = Instant::now();

    println!();
    println!("Json parser: {} ms", (t1 - t0).as_millis());
    println!("Computation: {} ms", (t2 - t1).as_millis());
}
```

Comment: "0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.646 total" on my pc with https://github.com/microprediction/muid/blob/master/muid/animals.json...

Comment: @Stargateur Wow. That's a beefy machine then. Compared to the python code?

Comment: Added multithreading code to demonstrate the real potential of Rust. @Stargateur Would you mind running this one, out of curiousity? Or is it now already bottlenecked by the json parser?

Comment: @Stargateur Removed your comment about the custom json parser again. See my multi threading code - it measures json parsing performance, and it's minor compared to the actual computation. Yes you can optimize it, but it's wasted effort imo.

Comment: "Json parser: 27 ms
Computation: 67 ms
target/release/lol.exe  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.254 total" python take between 10s and 20s, I just have a Ryzen 5 3600...